# Поменять местами числа в файле

Tags: c, файлы

Вот у меня есть среднее арифметическое и файл с числами. Нужно чтобы числа которые меньше среднего арифметического стояли в начали, а остальные после них. Без использования другого файла.
Записываю так

```
int a;
if((fp=fopen("nums.dat","w+"))!=NULL)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
       scanf("%d", &a);
       fwrite (&a, sizeof(int),1,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Отлично. А в чём вопрос?

Кстати, вы затираете содержимое файла при открытии, знаете, да?

Comment: VladD, Знаю. Только правда не пойму почему последнее число два раза пишется. Вопрос в том как поменять местами числа после того как я их сравнил со своим числом.

Comment: Вы бы разделили задачу на части:

1. Прочитать числа (понятно, в массив)
2. Найти среднее арифметическое
3. Вывести те элементы массива, которые меньше этого самого среднего арифметического
4. Вывести те, которые больше или равны.

А то вы пытаетесь сделать всё одновременно.

Comment: @VladD, мне надо именно в файле поменять, но все я понял что с массивом все просто будет, а то я привязался к идее что их переставлять в процессе надо и туплю сижу. Но вот не подскажешь почему последнее число два раза записывается (или считывается так).

Comment: @RubyNub: Во-первых, `scanf` читает не из файла, а с консоли. Во-вторых, стоит не игнорировать [код возврата](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), который показывает возможную ошибку.

Comment: @VladD, извиняюсь что занял время ваше. Разобрался сам потихоньку, надо просто меньше лениться.

Comment: @RubyNub, это Вы что-то не то смотрите (или Ваша программа это не только приведенный здесь код).

Код в вопросе запишет ровно 5 чисел (20 байт), прочитанных из stdout (даже переназначенного из `nul` или своего исходника) в файл `nums.dat` в том оглавлении, где вы ее запускаете.

Comment: @avp, естественно моя программа не только приведенный здесь код. Им я показал лишь то как заношу, потому что считал что только эта часть имеет отношение к моему вопросу. http://pastebin.com/AkKdxYFH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@RubyNub](/users/6638/rubynub), комментарии кончились, поэтому в ответе.

1. Все таки открывайте файл `fopen(..., "wb+");
2. Замените в печати результата `fread` на

   ```
     if (fread(&a, sizeof(int),1, fp) > 0)
        printf("%d ", a);
   ```

Дело в том, что EOF определяется fread-ом, а Вы его не проверяете, вот и печатаете лишний раз (6-й) последнее значение `a`.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще будет сделать вот такой алгоритм.

Открыть файл.
Считать данные в массив.
Закрыть файл.
Отсортировать массив так как нужно вам.
Открыть файл.
Записать в файл.
Закрыть файл.

А в указанном вами коде, вы просто в цикле считывает с клавиатуры какое то значение и пишите его в файл.

```
если файл открылся   
{
    повторяем действия 5 раз
    {
        считываем целое число с стандартного потока ввода(клавиатура).  
        записываем полученное число в открытый ранее файл. 
    }
}
закрываем файл
```

Ваш код абсолютно не имеет ни какого отношение к вашему вопросу.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, насчет отношения кода к вопросу, я бы не был столь категоричен.

IMHO это код создания файла, который предстоит сортировать.

--

@RubyNub, в принципе рассортировать прямо Ваш файл, да еще и в пространстве ядра вполне возможно. Посмотрите `man mmap`.

Comment: Спасибо я прекрасно понимаю мой код. Вы молодец показали что тоже понимаете его.

Comment: а вам обязательно на С нужен код, или на С++ пойдет? просто на С++ в файловых потоках можно сразу в файле данные изменять.
хотя посмотрев код на пастбине я увидел что там и С++ присутствует.

Comment: Ну, на Си тоже никто не мешает это делать.

Comment: на С++ открывается файл и с него можно и читать, и перезаписывать, и добавлять и все это на лету.     
а на С придется все таки переоткрывать файл с разными режимами доступа.     
хотя я с С плохо знаком )

Comment: В Си нужно 

      fopen(filename, "r+");

а в случае, если надо делать новый

      fopen(filename, "w+");

после `fseek()` можно с чтения переходить на запись и наоборот.

Comment: Вообщем тот код странно работает. ввод: 10 10 5 5 5
вывод: 5 5 10 10 10. То есть откуда-то лишняя десятка падает.

Comment: @RubyNub, ради интереса попробовал. Только в винде надо открывать `fopen("nums.dat", "wb+")`, иначе при выводе 10 (это '\n') будет символом '\r' предваряться.

Все работает

     c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
     10 10 5 5 5
     c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ od -d nums.dat
     0000000    10     0    10     0     5     0     5     0
     0000020     5     0
     0000024
     c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ 

Дополнительные нули, это потому что `od` по умолчанию берет 16-битные слова.

Comment: @avp, я имел ввиду код с пастебина